# Get Lat/Long with click by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, onclick

I want when I click on map I can get Lat/Long and show it in alert()
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is simple and I got it from [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_intro)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    // get a marker if you want
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
    // alert out the lat/lng...
    alert('Lat:' + event.latLng.lat() + ', Lng:' + event.latLng.lng());

});
```